# Newbie questions - Android Webview for view a snapshot of webcam?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I am a newbie.I want to creat a app that gets the stream from my webcam.I have set up a webcam and I have built a Wi-Fi wireless home network.My webcam communicate with other device using Wi-Fi network.

This is my webcam's URL: http://192.168.0.1:8080/?action=snapshot

First, I try to creat a app that gets the snapshot from my webcam using Webview,then I will build a timer command for automatically refresh the webview page per 0.04 seconds. Unfortunately, I have fail in first step.

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);

        setContentView(webview);

        webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.1:8080/?action=snapshot");
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If I open this file on my phone, it can not show anything to me 
but if I open my webcam's URL in Chrome or Browser on my phone it can display the snapshot of my webcam.

What is the problem in my code? Can anyone tell me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing All your networking code.

you can't pass a URL like that

check this example on android DOCS

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

hope it will help you.

if you still need help let me know

and i think you are missing INTERNET permission too.

Comment: I have import <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> to the AndroidManifest.xml but it is still not work

Comment: Try this code, and then replace www.google.com with your url. if you still get any error tell me

 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
        

        mWebView = new WebView(this);

        mWebView.loadUrl(uri.toString());